# kubectl run not creating deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm running Kubernetes with docker desktop on windows. DD is up-to-date, and the `kubectl version` command returns 1.22 as both the client and server version.

I executed `kubectl run my-apache --image httpd`, then `kubectl get all`, which only shows
[image]

There is no deployment or replicaset as I expect. This means some commands, such as `kubectl scale` doesn't work. Any idea what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kubectl run` command create pod not deployment, I mean it used to create in the past before kubernetes version 1.18 I guess.

For deployment you have run this command

`kubectl create deployment my-apache --image httpd`

Answer (score 1):

You basically spin up a pod in the default namespace, if you want to deploy your app using deployment you should have a `deployment.yml` file and use :

```sh
kubectl apply -f <depoyment_file>
```

Example to spin-up 3 Nginx pods:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Side note: There are 2 approaches when creating basic k8s objects:

- IMPERATIVE way:

```sh
kubectl create deployment <DEPLOYMENT_NAME> --image=<IMAGE_NAME:TAG>
```

- DECLARATIVE way:

```sh
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```